# Recording input from two routes simultaneously on iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiosession

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360784/choose-between-built-in-mic-and-headset-in-ios) talks about switching the audio input route, but I'm wondering if it's possible to take input from two routes simultaneously. I am working on an application that will record audio using an external microphone to help deal with noise, but I would also like to record with the internal microphone too so I can compare the two.

I feel like this will take quite a bit of digging through the AVAudioSession docs to figure out, and having a quick yes or no answer before then would save me a lot of time.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Though I haven't used it myself but.. Have you tried setting `AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute` category in `AVAudioSession`.

This is what [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) says - 
*For routing distinct streams of audio data to different output devices at the same time. For example, you would use this category to route audio to both a USB device and a set of headphones. Use of this category requires a more detailed knowledge of, and interaction with, the capabilities of the available audio routes.
This category may be used for input, output, or both.*

Usage example -

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

Please let me know/comment if it doesn't help so I delete this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it. For multiple audio devices, you are supposed to use the category `AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute`, but the `AVAudioSession.h` header file has this to say on input:

```
 Input is limited to the last-in input port.
```