# Possible to record audio through microphone jack, play separate sound through speaker on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, core-audio

I have a device similar to the Square reader that plugs in to the audio jack of an iPad and feeds in very simple data. I'm using [Novocaine](https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine) to read the raw data, but I'm having a problem playing audio through the speaker simultaneously.

Is it possible to record input from the headphone jack while playing sound through the speaker? If I set `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute` to `kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker`, the route for the input is changed as well. From what I can tell, it's [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360784/choose-between-built-in-mic-and-headset-in-ios) [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175082/force-iphone-to-output-through-the-speaker-while-recording-from-headphone-mic) to set the input and output routes independently.

Is it possible to drop down a level and use [Remote IO units](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/UsingSpecificAudioUnits/UsingSpecificAudioUnits.html) to accomplish this? Is there any higher-level API I can use? Does anyone have an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do this for an app of mine and was unable to find a way to do it, and I'm working at the lowest level, with Core Audio units, specifically Remote IO units.

The relevant method would be overrideOutputAudioPort:. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioSession/overrideOutputAudioPort%3aerror%3a):

> overrideOutputAudioPort:error: Temporarily changes the current audio
>   route.
>
> - (BOOL)overrideOutputAudioPort:(AVAudioSessionPortOverride)portOverride
>     error:(NSError **)outError Parameters portOverride The override option
>     for output. For a list of constants, see “AVAudioSessionPortOverride”.
>     outError On input, a pointer to an error object. If an error occurs,
>     the pointer is set to an NSError object that describes the error. If
>     you do not want error information, pass in nil. Return Value YES if
>     the new routing option was set successfully, or NO if it was not.
>
> Discussion Calling this method with the
>   AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker option and the audio session’s
>   category is AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord causes audio to use
>   the built-in speaker and microphone regardless of other settings. This
>   change will only be in effect until the current route changes or you
>   call this method again with the AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone option.